# creating an array whose elements are javascript objects with a certain property

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I apologize in advance for the very basic question. I have a javascript page on which I create a number of objects, and assign those objects certain properties. What I would like to do is create an array whose elements are all and only those objects which have a certain property. I know how to create (e.g.) an array whose elements are all and only those DOM elements with a certain class; but I can't figure out how to do the parallel thing with javascript objects with a certain property.

I recognize that I could do this manually via an array literal. What I am looking for is a way to generate the array automatically, so that when new javascript objects with the relevant property are added, they are automatically added to the array.

For example, if I have

const firstconstant = {
type: "A",
};

const secondconstant = {
type: "B",
};

const thirdconstant = {
type: "A",
};

etc. I'd like a way of generating an array whose elements are all of the objects with type "A". Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: In what way are the "new javascript objects" added? Do you add them manually?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I add the new objects manually.

Comment: Do you have an array like this `[{type: "A"}, {type: "B"}, {type: "C"}]`, and you want to convert it into this `[{type: "A"}]`.

Comment: Rather creating multiple variables, create one parent array and push values. When needed, just `filter` the unneeded values.

Comment: No, not exactly. It may help if I describe the use case. I am a teacher and construct a web site for students which generates questions for them to answer. Which questions they get depend on their answers to prior questions. The new constants I manually add are new questions, which may be of various types (multiple choice, essay, etc.). The javascript coding which determines which questions get shown relies on arrays whose members are all and only the questions of a certain type. Right now, when I add a new question I manually modify the relevant array literal. Was looking for a better way!

Answer (score 0):

There's no point for declaring a new variable for every new object, that's the reason arrays were invented - so you don't have to type firstconstant, secondconstant, thirdconstant etc.

First declare an array with all the objects (and add them here):

```js
const objects = [
    { type: "A" },
    { type: "B" },
    { type: "A" },
];
```

And then you can use the `.filter` method to filter out the objects that don't match:

```js
const filtered = objects.filter(object => object.type === "A");
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I should have done in the first place. I appreciate you taking the time to reply to such a dumb question.